# Can I have separate Game Center accounts on two different iOS devices registered to the same Apple ID?

Tags: ipod-touch, apple-id, game-center

Our kids each have an iPod touch and share my iTunes account.  My son now has my daughter's Game Center info on his iPod touch..  Can we get a separate Game Center ID for him?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - the Game Center sign-in can be the same or different than the Apple ID entered in other places (i.e. iTunes Store and iCloud).

[Make your son an Apple ID](http://appleid.apple.com) for his Game Center and later he can use it for other uses.